# IISNode fails with HTTP 500.1001 on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

Here's the only error message I've been able to find, from an error file in `/LogFiles/W3SVC1180911273`:

`ModuleName iisnode
Notification    EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
HttpStatus  500
HttpReason  Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus   1001
ErrorCode   The system cannot find the file specified.
 (0x2)`

I have a project I've been developing locally that I'm trying to now host to Azure. It's a Node project using socket.io, Webpack, and Typescript for the server-side and client-side JS. I haven't been able to get it working. Navigating to the site gives me a "This page isn’t working" 500 error.

I've created a custom `deploy.cmd` file that runs webpack and compiles my typescript. I've created an `iisnode.yml` file to make sure `loggingEnabled: true` is set. I've turned on Web Sockets in azure, and ensured that `<webSocket enabled="false" />` is set in my site's generated `web.config`, though I don't think sockets are the issue.

I also made sure that the express app is listening on `process.env.PORT` so that it uses the named pipe from Azure.

I use a `site log tail` to view the node logs and when I first navigate to the site after starting it, I see my node server start up successfully, without errors, and begin running. But the request always fails, multiple times in a row.

I can't find anywhere that it says what the actual file is that it can't find.

I previously had some `ENOENT: no such file or directory` errors thrown by node, and those showed up in my `/site/LogFiles/Application/logging-errors.txt` file, as well as my streaming logs. So the issue isn't with Node, it's with IISNode. And I can't figure out where to get more details about what's failing.

I'd greatly appreciate anyone being able to help me figure this out.

Comment: maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760975/iisnode-periodically-fails-with-http-500-1001-on-azure Wait a few minutes and try again after you get that error.

Comment: Yeah, that's the question I pulled the title from. Like I said, I've tried multiple times in a row. I've tried after several minutes and after hours, it's always the same error.

Comment: Any luck with that? I have the same problem.